# How to change existing column with alpha 2 country code to alpha 3 country code in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How to change existing column with
alpha 2 country code to alpha 3 country code in postgresql?

For example

```
Afghanistan AF  AFG
Albania     AL  ALB
```

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit, because Ivo's answer doesn't match your new question any more. Please do **not** change your question after you have received an answer. Create a new question instead. However it would be much better to tell us **all** requirements you have right from the start, rather than adding new problems after each answer you get.

Comment: Yup..Thank you for your guidance. I'm newly using stack overflow. Sorry for the incoinvenice caused.  Noted your comment. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mapping table with 2 columns:

```
+------+------+
| ISO2 | ISO3 |
+------+------+
```

and populate the table with all the ISO country codes.

Then, first change your column definition from **CHAR(2)** to **CHAR(3)** in the original table and then update the existing values:

```sql
UPDATE myDataTable, myMappingTable 
SET myDataTable.ISO2_CODE = myMappingTable.ISO3
WHERE myDataTable.ISO2_CODE = myMappingTable.ISO2
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. One more question While creating new table I want to add column with alpha 3 country code ? How to get alpha 3 country code for code coulmn in a table?

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: Wikipedia has all ISO2 and ISO3 country codes - but I do not think there is a premade mapping between the two; you will have to match them manually, country by country.

Comment: Google "ISO 3166".  It will return multiple sites which offer downloads that map the 2 and 3 character codes for all 249 countries.